# How to loop all category posts except the open one in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, loops, posts

in my single.php i want to show all category posts except the opened post.

Here is my code: [pastebin.com loop code](http://pastebin.com/7cgddUTV)

Here is the code for category posts loop, it loops all category posts and the opened one, i do not want to loop opened post again

```
<?php $catid = the_category_ID( false ); ?> 
                        <?php $postCount = 1; $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'tax_query' => array(array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => $catid
                            )), 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 15 ) ); if ($loop->have_posts()) { ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

I have the solution:

```
<?php $catid = get_the_category(); $catid = $catid[0]->term_id; ?>
                        <?php $postCount = 1; $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'tax_query' => array(array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => $catid
                            )),
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'posts_per_page' => 15,
                            'post__not_in' =>array($post->ID) ) );
                        if ($loop->have_posts()) { ?>
```

U need to use 'post_not_in' option.

Answer (score 0):

Use this : (example avoiding category 3)

```
 query_posts( 'cat=-3' );
```

Check this : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Exclude_Categories_From_Your_Home_Page

Then in your page you just have to check the category of the Post where you are and replace "-3" by the category ID you want to avoid.

Comment: I think you dont understand my question. Option 'cat=-3' hides all category posts. I need to hide only the post which are opened. And i have not one category, i have 10 categories and only one single.php

Comment: Oh! Sorry. You can try to use 'relation' => 'AND' in you Tax query, you do one with cat=-$catid and another with all cats. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters